# Azure function / powershell: Trying to find ObjectID of user by doing lookup of email address. "Connect-AzureAD is not recognized"

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have been banging my head against the wall trying to get this to work.
Just to be clear, **I am not running this locally**.  This runs fine when I run it locally in powershell cli.

I am running this as an Azure Function App.  The weird thing is that a few lines above this I have similar code to connect to PnPOnline - that works fine.

**Goal**:  I need to be able to pass an email address to AD and retrieve the ObjectID of that user.  Again, works fine locally.

```
  $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, 
  $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)   
  Import-Module AzureAD
  Connect-AzureAD -Credentials $cred
```

The error:

```
The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I'm not used to powershell functions, but the error seems like when you don't have the powershell module installed in local. So I think you have to reference that module, try something like this https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/install-azuread-and-azureadpreview-module-in-powershell-function/ba-p/2644778

Comment: Thanks so much for the comment - I completely forgot about the requirements.psd1 as I have been away from this for a while.  I am now getting a timeout error - not sure if that is good or bad.  Still playing.

Comment: I am currently working through this error:

he current processor architecture is: X86.  The module 'C:\home\data\ManagedDependencies\2111192104261737660.r\AzureAD\2.0.2.140\AzureAD.psd1' requires the following architecture: Amd64.

Comment: Ok, the x86 was caused by having the OS set to be 32 instead of 64.  I was reading through an article from 2019 where it required it to be 32 bit - unfortunately I didn't finish the  thread. 

        Import-Module AzureAD -UseWindowsPowershell
        Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred   
        
        $ADUser =  Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq "someEmail@something.com"}

Now working through this error:  The term 'Get-ADUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: `Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell` (OR) `Get-WindowsCapability -Name RSAT.ActiveDirectory* -Online | Add-WindowsCapability -Online` - execute this command. Get-ADUser is part of the active directory module.

Comment: You're not going to be able to use Get-ADUser in functions. It should be Get-AzureADUser. I threw together a quick GitHub repo on setting up an Azure function with azureAD here: https://github.com/brettmillerb/azureadfunction

Comment: Thank you all so much!  I marked the first answer as the correct one as it applied to the original question.
@BrettMiller, I appreciate your answer as well!

Comment: @AdamCodes716  Glad that your issue got resolved could you please help us with the resolution steps as an answer so that it will be helpful for the other community members if they face any similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

> The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
> function, script file, or operable program.

The error occurs because AzureAD module is not installed.

You can install AzureAD module using the below command:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

Once the AzureAD module is installed, you can import the AzureAD module in your powershell script using below command:

```
Import-Module AzureAD
```

Now you can connect to the Azure AD and get the user object id using the below script:

```
Import-Module AzureAD
$secpasswd = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force;$cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName, $secpasswd);
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $cred;
$ADUser = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq 'someEmail@something.com'"
```